# Android AsyncTask con PHP

Tags: php, java, android

Tengo una problema un poco raro con `Asyctask` y `php`.
Si en `php` pongo echo "1-1"; todo funciona correcto. Pero si pongo `php` con `mysql` y la respuesta es 1-1 no funciona. He puesto un `Task` en `android` y veo lo que lea de `php`, la respuesta en `android` es 1-1 pero con mucho espacio antes, algo así "      1-1".
Como puedo solucionar esta problema? E intentado con sacar del `string` el espacio,pero no a funcionado tampoco.Y en la web `php mysal` esta claro que la respuesta es 1-1 sin nada de espacio.

Android JaVa

```
private class AsyncRetrieve extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainPageActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    //this method will interact with UI, here display loading message
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    // This method does not interact with UI, You need to pass result to onPostExecute to display
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            final String str12 = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            // Enter URL address where your php file resides
            url = new URL("http://www.ssss.ss/api/puente.php?dni=" + str12);


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    // this method will interact with UI, display result sent from doInBackground method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("0-0")) {
           // Toast.makeText(MainPageActivity.this, "nada elegido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPageActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Nada elegido");
            builder.setMessage("No has elegido ningun puente hasta ahora! Queres elegir ahora? ");

            // add a button
            builder.setPositiveButton("Si",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    texts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texts);
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    final String str = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Puente.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("dni", str);
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            // create and show the alert dialog
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }else{
            if(result.equals("0-1")) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPageActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Has elegido solo las 50%");
                builder.setMessage("Has elegido 23,26,27 Diciembre! Queres elegir ahora los de 33%? ");

                // add a button
                builder.setPositiveButton("Si",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        texts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texts);
                        Intent intent = getIntent();
                        final String str = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Puente2.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("dni", str);
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                // create and show the alert dialog
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }else{
                if(result.equals("0-2")) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPageActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Has elegido solo las 50%");
                    builder.setMessage("Has elegido 30 Diciembre y 2,3 enero! Queres elegir ahora los de 33%? ");

                    // add a button
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Si",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, close
                            // current activity
                            texts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texts);
                            Intent intent = getIntent();
                            final String str = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Puente2.class);
                            myIntent.putExtra("dni", str);
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, close
                            // current activity
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    // create and show the alert dialog
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                }else{
                    // you to understand error returned from doInBackground method
                    if(result.equals("1-0")) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPageActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Has elegido solo las 33%");
                        builder.setMessage("Has elegido 15,16,17 Abril! Queres elegir ahora los de 50%? ");

                        // add a button
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Si",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                texts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texts);
                                Intent intent = getIntent();
                                final String str = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Puente3.class);
                                myIntent.putExtra("dni", str);
                            }
                        });

                        builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                        // create and show the alert dialog
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();

                    }else{
                        if(result.equals("                              1-1")) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainPageActivity.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPageActivity.this);
                            builder.setTitle("Todo corecto");
                            builder.setMessage("Has elegido 15,16,17 Abril y 23,26,27 Diciembre! ");



                            builder.setPositiveButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, close
                                    // current activity
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                            // create and show the alert dialog
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();


                        }else{
                            if(result.equals("1-2")) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPageActivity.this);
                                builder.setTitle("Todo corecto");
                                builder.setMessage("Has elegido 15,16,17 Abril y 30 Diciembre 2,3 Enero! ");



                                builder.setPositiveButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, close
                                        // current activity
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                                // create and show the alert dialog
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();

                            }else{
                                if(result.equals("2-0")) {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPageActivity.this);
                                    builder.setTitle("Falta elegir 50%");
                                    builder.setMessage("Has elegido 29,30 abril y 3 Mayo! Queres elegir ahora los de 50%? ");

                                    // add a button
                                    builder.setPositiveButton("Si",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                            // if this button is clicked, close
                                            // current activity
                                            texts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texts);
                                            Intent intent = getIntent();
                                            final String str = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Puente2.class);
                                            myIntent.putExtra("dni", str);
                                        }
                                    });

                                    builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                            // if this button is clicked, close
                                            // current activity
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    // create and show the alert dialog
                                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                    dialog.show();

                                }else{
                                    if(result.equals("2-1")) {
                                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPageActivity.this);
                                        builder.setTitle("Todo Correcto");
                                        builder.setMessage("Has elegido 29,30Abril y 3 Mayo! Y 23,26,27 Diciembre! ");

                                        // add a button


                                        builder.setPositiveButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                                // current activity
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                            }
                                        });
                                        // create and show the alert dialog
                                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                        dialog.show();

                                    }else{
                                        if(result.equals("2-2")) {
                                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPageActivity.this);
                                            builder.setTitle("Todo Correcto!");
                                            builder.setMessage("Has elegido 29,20 Abril y 3 Mayo! Queres elegir ahora los de 50%? ");

                                            // add a button


                                            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                                    // if this button is clicked, close
                                                    // current activity
                                                    dialog.cancel();
                                                }
                                            });
                                            // create and show the alert dialog
                                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                            dialog.show();

                                        }else{
                                            if(result.equals("3-0")) {
                                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPageActivity.this);
                                                builder.setTitle("Falta elegir 50%");
                                                builder.setMessage("Has elegido 2,3,4,5 Diciembre Abril! Queres elegir ahora los de 50%? ");

                                                // add a button
                                                builder.setPositiveButton("Si",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                                        // if this button is clicked, close
                                                        // current activity
                                                        texts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texts);
                                                        Intent intent = getIntent();
                                                        final String str = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                                                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Puente2.class);
                                                        myIntent.putExtra("dni", str);
                                                    }
                                                });

                                                builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                                        // if this button is clicked, close
                                                        // current activity
                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                                // create and show the alert dialog
                                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                                dialog.show();

                                            }else{
                                                if(result.equals("3-1")) {
                                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPageActivity.this);
                                                    builder.setTitle("Todo correcto");
                                                    builder.setMessage("Has elegido 2,3,4,5 Diciembre ! 30 Diciembre 2 y 3 Enero! ");

                                                    // add a button


                                                    builder.setPositiveButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                                            // if this button is clicked, close
                                                            // current activity
                                                            dialog.cancel();
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                    // create and show the alert dialog
                                                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                                    dialog.show();

                                                }else{
                                                    if(result.equals("3-2")) {
                                                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainPageActivity.this);
                                                        builder.setTitle("Todo correcto");
                                                        builder.setMessage("Has elegido 2,3,4,5 Diciembre ! 30 Diciembre 2 y 3 Enero! ");



                                                        builder.setPositiveButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                                                // current activity
                                                                dialog.cancel();
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                        // create and show the alert dialog
                                                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                                        dialog.show();
                                                    }else{
                                                        result = result.replace(" " , "");
                                                        // you to understand error returned from doInBackground method
                                                        Toast.makeText(MainPageActivity.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                    }


                                                }


                                            }


                                        }


                                    }


                                }


                            }


                        }


                    }


                }


            }


        }

    }

}
```

Php

```
<?php       
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "g";
    $password = "s*";
    $dbname = "n";

    $dni  = $_GET['dni'];                                           

    /// Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= '$dni'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              echo "" . $row["puente33"]. "-" . $row["puente50"]. "";
            }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

la respuesta en php es 1-1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si borro todo el código php y pongo solo `echo"1-1"`; funciona correcto.

Gracias por todo

Comment: Prueba con __result.trim();__ también te recomiendo implementar json, en estos casos en los que se transporta datos de un servidor a cualquier cliente son muy útiles.

Comment: A funcionado, e cambiado result.trim().equals

Answer (score 0):

E cambiado `result.equals` por `result.trim().equals` y todo a funcionado corecto. Gracias a Juan Lozoya.

Comment: Y que voi a acceptar si no hay respuesta, el usuario a puesto solo un comentario